# Estoy teniendo problemas con un juego simple que estoy queriendo hacer con html y js

Tags: javascript, html, css

Como están?
El día de hoy vengo a pedir ayuda con un código que estoy aprendiendo, sinceramente hace menos de un mes que empecé con la programación y de momento me estaba yendo bien, hasta que hace unos días que estoy intentando hacer un modelo de jueguito en el que hay dos paletas que se pasan una pelotita sin embargo a la hora de cargar la pagina dicho juego no se ve relejado y de momento se que estoy llamando bien al juego en el HTML por lo que después de tanto tiempo decidí pedir ayuda por aquí.
Este es mi codigo:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    
    const ballRadius = 10;
    let ballX = canvas.width/2;
    let ballY = canvas.height/2;
    let ballSpeedX = 5;
    let ballSpeedY = 5;
    
    const paddleHeight = 75;
    const paddleWidth = 10;
    let paddle1Y = (canvas.height - paddleHeight) / 2;
    let paddle2Y = (canvas.height - paddleHeight) / 2;
    const paddleSpeed = 10;
    
    let score1 = 0;
    let score2 = 0;
    
    function draw() {
      // Limpiar el canvas
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    
      // Dibujar las paletas
      ctx.fillStyle = "white";
      ctx.fillRect(0, paddle1Y, paddleWidth, paddleHeight);
      ctx.fillRect(canvas.width - paddleWidth, paddle2Y, paddleWidth, paddleHeight);
    
      // Dibujar la pelota
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(ballX, ballY, ballRadius, 0, Math.PI*2);
      ctx.fillStyle = "white";
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.closePath();
    
      // Actualizar la posición de la pelota
      ballX += ballSpeedX;
      ballY += ballSpeedY;
    
      // Detectar colisiones con los bordes de la pantalla
      if(ballY + ballRadius > canvas.height || ballY - ballRadius < 0) {
        ballSpeedY = -ballSpeedY;
      }
      if(ballX + ballRadius > canvas.width || ballX - ballRadius < 0) {
        // La pelota ha salido de la pantalla, aumentar la puntuación del jugador correspondiente
        if(ballX - ballRadius < 0) {
          score2++;
        } else {
          score1++;
        }
    
        // Colocar la pelota de nuevo en el centro
        ballX = canvas.width/2;
        ballY = canvas.height/2;
        ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedX;
        ballSpeedY = -ballSpeedY;
    
        // Reproducir sonido de perder una vida
        let lifeLostSound = document.getElementById("lifeLostSound");
        lifeLostSound.currentTime = 0;
        lifeLostSound.play();
      }
    
      // Detectar colisiones con las paletas
      if(ballX - ballRadius < paddleWidth) {
        if(ballY > paddle1Y && ballY < paddle1Y + paddleHeight) {
          ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedX;
          let paddleSound = document.getElementById("paddleSound");
          paddleSound.currentTime = 0;
          paddleSound.play();
        }
      }
      if(ballX + ballRadius > canvas.width - paddleWidth) {
        if(ballY > paddle2Y && ballY < paddle2Y + paddleHeight) {
          ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedX;
          let paddleSound = document.getElementById("paddleSound");
          paddleSound.currentTime = 0;
          paddleSound.play();
        }
    }
    
    // Mover las paletas
    document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    if(event.key === "w" && paddle1Y > 0) {
    paddle1Y -= paddleSpeed;
    } else if(event.key === "s" && paddle1Y + paddleHeight < canvas.height) {
    paddle1Y += paddleSpeed;
    } else if(event.key === "ArrowUp" && paddle2Y > 0) {
    paddle2Y -= paddleSpeed;
    } else if(event.key === "ArrowDown" && paddle2Y + paddleHeight < canvas.height) {
    paddle2Y += paddleSpeed;
    }
    });
    
    // Dibujar la puntuación
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.font = "30px Arial";
    ctx.fillText(score1, canvas.width/4, 50);
    ctx.fillText(score2, canvas.width*3/4, 50);
    }
    
    setInterval(draw, 16); // Actualizar la pantalla 60 veces por segundo.
```

```css
canvas {
        background-color: black;
      }
    
    /* Paletas */
    paddle1 {
        background-color: white;
      }
    paddle2 {
        background-color: white;
      }
      
      /* Pelota */
    .ball {
        background-color: white;
        border-radius: 50%;
      }
      
      /* Puntuación */
    .score {
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 30px;
        color: white;
      }
      .game-canvas {
        background-color: black;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es">
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
      <script src="pong.js"></script>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>My Game</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <canvas id="canvas" width="480" height="320" class="game-canvas"></canvas>
      <audio id="paddleSound" src="song/Ping Pong Ball Hit.mp3"></audio>
      <audio id="brickSound" src="song/Ping Pong Ball Hit.mp3"></audio>
      <audio id="lifeLostSound" src="song/error-fallo-1.mp3"></audio>
      
    </body>
```

Sepan disculpar las molestias, no me gusta la idea de andar pidiendo ayuda por ahi, les agradezco si me explican <3

Comment: Sinceramente lo escribi tal cual y no se ve cuando abro la pagina :(
A la hora de abrir el html solo se ve un borde negro pero nada mas, como estaria importando bien los archivos? porque hice un html, un css y pong.js y hasta donde se los estoy importando bien en el html
En la pagina cuando abro la consola me dice esto: 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getContext')
    at pong.js:2:20
index.html:44 Live reload enabled.
Ping%20Pong%20Ball%20Hit.mp3:1 
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_OPERATION_NOT_SUPPORTED... 
lamento mi poco conocimiento..

Comment: El problema es que estás importando el archivo antes de que el DOM (es decir como el contenido) esté cargado... por eso se ejecuta el buscar el canvas antes de que el canvas si quiera exista.

Comment: Pipe! Me podrias explicar asi te entiendo mucho mejor? Gracias!!!

Comment: SIIIII, GRACIAS!!!!